# python - 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, sqlite

First time python user here, be gentle.... ;-)

Python 2.6 on OSX

Got a class which just has some wrappers around sqlite... here it is

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

class SqliteDB:
    connection = ''
    curser = ''

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite.connect("pagespeed.sqlite")
            self.curser = self.connection.cursor()
         except sqlite.Error, e:
            print "Ooops: ", e.args[0]

    def find_or_create(self, table, column, value):
        self.curser.execute("SELECT id FROM ? WHERE ?=? LIMIT 1", (table, column, value))
        records = self.curser.fetchall()
        if records.count() == false:
            self.curser.execute("INSERT into ? SET ?=?", (table, column, value))
            self.curser.execute("SELECT id FROM ? WHERE ?=? LIMIT 1", (table, column, value))
        print records
```

and I call it like this in a separate file

```
import sqlitedb

def main():
    db = sqlitedb.SqliteDB()
    db.connect    
    url_id = db.find_or_create('urls', 'url', 'http://www.example.com')
```

however I get this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "update_urls.py", line 17, in <module>

  main()

  File "update_urls.py", line 11, in main

  url_id = db.find_or_create('urls', 'url', 'http://www.example.com')

  File "....../sqlitedb.py", line 16, in find_or_create

  self.curser.execute("SELECT id FROM ? WHERE ?=? LIMIT 1", (table, column, value))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

So it's almost like self.curser is not getting a curser, or is self not correct?

Not to sure if what I am doing is right here....

cheers

Comment: You may think it amusing to use `curser` as a variable name but anyone who needs to read your code will be cursing your name as they nut through the code to detect whether it's a typo for `cursor` or not.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was going for cursor but my english is that bad... and it's my only language (english). Poor form to not know how to spell properly at my age.

Comment: Thanks all for the great feedback as well, just about to duck out for 10 mins and will check and award the answer when i'm back. 

I also VERY much appreciate the feedback on other sections of code, very helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong, but at the very least:

```
db.connect
```

should be

```
db.connect()
```

e.g. call the function.

OK. S.Lott had the answer, I just found an other bug :)

Comment: No... you found the bug, S. Lott found a nitpick. With his correction, OP will just get the same error but with `NoneType` instead of `str`.

Comment: er, scratch that. OP would get an `AttributeError`. Popped into my head when thinking about something completely different. Ad it is good advice.

Comment: @aaronsterling: Huh? You were right first time. Previously, self.curser refers to class attribute, value ''. After S.Lott change (but not fixing not calling connect method): instance attribute, value None. So: from `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'` to `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Comment: @John Machin, no because the change moves the creation of `connection` and `curser_sic` into the `connect` method which is never called. When `find_or_create` is then called, you should get `AttributeError: 'SqliteDB' object has not attribute 'curser_sic'`. right? So it's still an `Attribute` error, just with a different attribute.

Comment: @aaronsterling: You are correct as to outcome. @S.Lott moved the creation of those 2 into the `__init__` method, which would be called, not the `connect` method. However @S.Lott also changed from `curser_sic` to `cursor` on the way to the `__init__`. Had he not done that, the outcome would have been as you suggested initially.

Comment: @John Machin. You're right, I don't know how I missed that `__init__` runs automatically in my calculations. I really can be remarkably stupid at times.

Comment: @aaronsterling: You were spot-on with the major conclusion (nitpick, not the real problem) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Do Not Do This.

```
class SqliteDB:
    connection = ''
    curser = ''
```

It doesn't "declare" any variables.  This isn't C++ or Java.

Do this.

```
class SqliteDB:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.connection = None
        self.cursor= None
```

Comment: Actually, it declares class variables (accessible through `self.connection` or `SqliteDB.connection`). As soon as you write to `self.connection` you create an instance variable (meaning only `SqliteDB.connection` will access the class variable now).

Comment: Zooba: You're very close.  It declares nothing.  It **creates** class level variables that are concealed by instance variables.  It's a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

And the 3rd bug:

```
self.curser.execute("SELECT id FROM ? WHERE ?=? LIMIT 1", (table, column, value))
```

You can't parameterise table names and column names. All you can parameterise are things that can be an expression in SQL syntax. You'll need to do something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM %s WHERE %s = ? LIMIT 1" % (table, column)
self.curser.execute(sql, (value, ))
```

Oh yeah, to save the flurry of comments: or use the modern `string.format(data)` method instead of the antique `string % data` operator.

Comment: string.format(data) was python 3 I thought? I will recheck but from my OP I am using 2.6. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: and here's a link: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101-advanced-string-formatting

Answer (score 1):

I will also add that this will not work :

```
curser.execute("SELECT id FROM ? WHERE ?=? LIMIT 1", (table, column, value))
```

because placeholders (?) doesn't work for table name, you should rather use string formatting before if you still want to use table name as parameter:

```
query = "SELECT id FROM %s WHERE %s=? LIMIT 1" % (table, column)
curser.execute(query, (value, ))
```

and one last thing "curser" is misspelled :)

Comment: great thanks for the feedback, my poor spelling as well :) thnks for your time